# Determine which page all footnotes landed on

Tags: page-numbering, auxiliary-files

How can I tell (after compilation) which page (column etc) a footnote was placed on, rather than on which page the start of its paragraph fell?

For example, in the following, footnote 7 falls on page two; however, in `\jobname.feet`, line 7 reads `7.p1`, when it "should" be `7.p2`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\def\lipf{\lipsum*[1]\footnote{aa}\par zz\footnote{bb}}

\newwrite\feet
\immediate\openout\feet=\jobname.feet

\deffootnote{1em}{2em}{\immediate\write\feet{\thefootnote.p\thepage}}

\begin{document}
\lipf\lipf\lipf\lipf
\end{document}
```

I know I 'should' use `\pageref` to refer to the genuine page on which a label occurs, but I don't know how to add this to each footnote, or how to write this information to a text file.

By way of background, I'm enforcing a style where `\deffootnote` is changed on the page of the 100th footnote and to do so I need to write a file that confirms the change was placed correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an automatic labeling to `\footnote` (more precisely, to `\@footnotetext`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@footnotetext}
  {#1}
  {#1\label{footnote@@@\thefootnote}}
  {}{}
\makeatother


\def\lipf{\lipsum*[1]\footnote{aa}\par zz\footnote{bb}}

\begin{document}
\lipf\lipf\lipf\lipf
\end{document}
```

Here's the contents of the `.aux` file relative to the footnotes:

```
\newlabel{footnote@@@1}{{1}{1}}
\newlabel{footnote@@@2}{{2}{1}}
\newlabel{footnote@@@3}{{3}{1}}
\newlabel{footnote@@@4}{{4}{1}}
\newlabel{footnote@@@5}{{5}{1}}
\newlabel{footnote@@@6}{{6}{1}}
\newlabel{footnote@@@7}{{7}{2}}
\newlabel{footnote@@@8}{{8}{2}}
```

Instead of writing a `\newlabel` command, something else can be written out for further processing at end document, similarly to how `\addcontentsline` works.

With `hyperref` the macro to patch is different; the following code works with or without it.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}
 {\patchcmd{\H@@footnotetext}}
 {\patchcmd{\@footnotetext}}
  {#1}
  {#1\label{footnote@@@\thefootnote}}
  {}{}
\makeatother


\def\lipf{\lipsum*[1]\footnote{aa}\par zz\footnote{bb}}

\begin{document}
\lipf\lipf\lipf\lipf
\end{document}
```

---

It's also possible to store the column when in two column format, with the help of `zref-savepos`.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{zref-savepos}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}
 {\patchcmd{\H@@footnotetext}}
 {\patchcmd{\@footnotetext}}
  {#1}
  {\zsaveposx{footnote@@@\thefootnote}#1\label{footnote@@@\thefootnote}}
  {}{}
\makeatother


\def\lipf{\lipsum*[1]\footnote{aa}\par zz\footnote{bb}}

\begin{document}
\lipf\lipf\lipf\lipf
\end{document}
```

The corresponding output in the `.aux` file is as follows, where it's clear what footnotes are in the left column and what in the right one.

```
\zref@newlabel{footnote@@@1}{\posx{6479946}}
\newlabel{footnote@@@1}{{1}{1}{}{Hfootnote.1}{}}
\zref@newlabel{footnote@@@2}{\posx{6479946}}
\newlabel{footnote@@@2}{{2}{1}{}{Hfootnote.2}{}}
\zref@newlabel{footnote@@@3}{\posx{20513024}}
\newlabel{footnote@@@3}{{3}{1}{}{Hfootnote.3}{}}
\zref@newlabel{footnote@@@4}{\posx{20513024}}
\newlabel{footnote@@@4}{{4}{1}{}{Hfootnote.4}{}}
\zref@newlabel{footnote@@@5}{\posx{20513024}}
\newlabel{footnote@@@5}{{5}{1}{}{Hfootnote.5}{}}
\zref@newlabel{footnote@@@6}{\posx{20513024}}
\newlabel{footnote@@@6}{{6}{1}{}{Hfootnote.6}{}}
\zref@newlabel{footnote@@@7}{\posx{6479946}}
\newlabel{footnote@@@7}{{7}{2}{}{Hfootnote.7}{}}
\zref@newlabel{footnote@@@8}{\posx{6479946}}
\newlabel{footnote@@@8}{{8}{2}{}{Hfootnote.8}{}}
```

Comment: What should I do if I use `\usepackage{hyperref}`?

Comment: @Hugh You should apply the patch before loading `hyperref`. I added a patch for both cases.

Comment: Yes (and for other readers, packages like `footmisc` should be loaded *before*). Another q: how can I also determine the *column* of the footnote if using `twocolumn`? I tried `if@firstcolumn\label{L.footnote@@@\thefootnote}\else\label{R.footnote@@@\thefootnote}\fi` but that detects the paragraph position.

Comment: @Hugh I can think to something with `zref-savepos` that can save in the `.aux` file the x-coordinate.

Answer (score 0):

This technically answers the question, but it also adds some `\hbox{}`es to `.feet` because I don't know what I'm doing.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand*\lipf{\lipsum*[1]\footnote{aa}\par zz\footnote{bb}}

\newwrite\feet
\immediate\openout\feet=\jobname.feet

\deffootnote{1em}{2em}{\textsuperscript{\thefootnotemark}\label{fn:\thefootnote}\immediate\write\feet{\ref{fn:\thefootnote}.p\pageref{fn:\thefootnote}}}

\begin{document}
\lipf\lipf\lipf\lipf
\end{document}
```

`.feet`:

```
1\hbox {}.p1\hbox {}
2\hbox {}.p1\hbox {}
3\hbox {}.p1\hbox {}
4\hbox {}.p1\hbox {}
5\hbox {}.p1\hbox {}
6\hbox {}.p1\hbox {}
7\hbox {}.p2\hbox {}
8\hbox {}.p2\hbox {}
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this without adding `\markfn` to every `\footnote`? (As in, I'd like to do this at the `cls` level.)

Comment: @Hugh Already done. See above. I realised I didn't need that as soon as I posted. (Benefit of hindsight.) Still includes all the `\hbox {}` things, though.